# Is it possible to multi-thread maven sub-projects?

Tags: multithreading, maven, maven-3

I have a maven project that has sub projects which have their own child projects, configured like so:

```
parent pom.xml listing sub-projects as modules
     sub-project 1 pom.xml listing child-projects as modules
          child project 1-1 pom.xml
          child project 1-2 pom.xml
     sub-project 2 pom.xml listing child-projects as modules
          child project 2-1 pom.xml
          child project 2-2 pom.xml
          child project 2-3 pom.xml
     sub-project 3 pom.xml listing child-projects as modules
          child project 3-1 pom.xml
```

Sub-project 3 depends on the output of sub-project 2, which in turn depends on the output of sub-project 1.

What I would like to accomplish is running each of the sub-projects serially, and all of the child projects in parallel. The desired order of execution would look like:

```
Build starts
sub-project 1 execution starts
all child projects of sub-project 1 are started in their own threads
all child projects of sub-project 1 finish execution
sub-project 1 execution ends
sub-project 2 execution starts
all child projects of sub-project 2 are started in their own threads
all child projects of sub-project 2 finish execution
sub-project 2 execution ends
sub-project 3 execution starts
all child projects of sub-project 3 are started in their own threads
all child projects of sub-project 3 finish execution
sub-project 3 execution ends
Build process completes
```

Using the -T command line argument for maven just starts executing all of the projects at once, like so:

```
Build starts
Start sub-project 1
start sub-project 2
Start sub-project 3
Start child project n...
```

Which fails because of dependencies between the sub-projects.

Is there any way to dictate a fine grained approach to how threads are used in maven?

Comment: If your build fails because of dependencies your build is flawed...The first test you should do is: Delete the local repo cache (`$HOME/.m2/repository`)  build your project via `mvn clean package`. This should work...otherwise your build is wrong...Furthermore using the most recent version of Maven is recommended.

Comment: @khmarbaise No offense intended, but "Your build is wrong" feels like a concrete life preserver thrown while I'm drowning. Could you expand on why my build may be wrong, and what steps I could take to rectify the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same use and couldn't achieve it using the -T option, as its just to tell maven to use multi-thread for building the project and if one subproject is dependent on other and it's not built yet , then obviously it will fail, instead of waiting(which IMO is correct thing to do, otherwise it could create deadlock and cause your system to hang).

Please refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3 for more information about the parallel builds in maven.

Comment: As mentioned above if this fails you havem missed to defined the correct dependencies between the modules...this is the issue here. Furthermore using the most recent version of Maven is recommended.

Comment: @Amit I read the maven link before posting my question, but I guess I'll take another look to see what I missed.

Comment: @bakoyaro, sounds good, let me know if you find some solution to your question

Comment: @Amit I don't agree with your statement that mavens behaviour is somehow good or correct. There no reason why maven should not be able to know which modules depend on which and there is no reason to believe that it would allow for circular dependencies on modules. Therefore its simply a bug that maven doesn't handle dependencies right. Yet, we cannot expect the maven team to do anything useful about it ...

Your own linked maven docs: This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project.